# Which Mail server application is best for CentOS

Tags: web-apps, email, imap, smtp, centos

I am looking for SMTP, IMAP and POP3 server and also a good control panel to manage, create and delete email accounts, users and domain names.

I searched on the web and founded several open source but got confused which one will be good with more features.

1. iRedMail
2. Modoboa
3. Mailu
4. Docker MailServer
5. hMail Email Server
6. Poste.io
7. Mail-in-a-Box
8. Apache James
9. MailSlurper
10. Magma Server Daemon

I cannot install all one by one to check which one is best. So, please suggest me from your knowledge and experience. Which one you using and which should i choose for my requirements?

Comment: What features are you looking for exactly?

Comment: sending, receiving, managing domain & users. Additionally i will be using roundcube for client